# Splunk: I am trying to create report by writing a query but the values are not displaying under statistics. How can I resolve this?

Tags: splunk

I am new to the Splunk tool. I am trying to create a report by using a query. The data is not getting loaded under `Statistics` but I can see the logs under the `Events`. Is there somthing that I am missing in my below query:

```
index="cba_strat_risk" sourcetype IN ("kube:container:abc-service", "kube:container:xyz-service") 
| stats count as count, count(eventtype="nix-all-logs") as success-count, count(eventtype="nix_errors") as error-count 
| eval success_percentage=round(success-count/count*100,2) 
| eval error_percentage=round(error-count/count*100,2) 
| fields sourcetype eventtype success-count error-count success_percentage error_percentage
```

Also attaching the screenshot:[image]

Please do let me know, if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work:

```
index="cba_strat_risk" sourcetype IN ("kube:container:abc-service", "kube:container:xyz-portal", "kube:container:zzz-landing") 
| stats count as total_count, count(eval(eventtype="nix-all-logs")) as success_count, count(eval(eventtype="nix_errors")) as error_count by sourcetype 
| eval success_percentage=round(success_count/total_count*100,2) 
| eval error_percentage=round(error_count/total_count*100,2) 
| rename sourcetype as Service 
| rename success_count as "Success Count" 
| rename error_count as "Error Count" 
| rename error_percentage as "Error Percentage" 
| rename success_percentage as "Success Percentage" 
| fields Service "Success Count" "Success Percentage" "Error Count" "Error Percentage"
```

Answer (score 2):

The Statistics tab is loaded by stats commands (like `stats`, `chart`, and `timechart`), which you have in your query.  The problem is the values shown are either null or zero.

First, avoid hyphens (a.k.a. minus signs) in field names.  They only lead to parsing problems.

Second, the construct `count(eventtype="nix-all-logs")` won't work.  To count the results of an expression, you must use `eval`, as in `count(eval(eventtype="nix-all-logs"))`.  However, in that case, `count` is not the function to use as it will return the number of ones and zeroes returned by `eval`.  Instead, use `sum(eval(eventtype="nix-all-logs"))` to get the number of events meeting the eval criteria.